# Azure Synapse Stored Procedure from Azure Data Factory: is it a synchronous call?

Tags: azure, stored-procedures, azure-data-factory, azure-synapse

I am calling a synapse stored procedure from my ADF pipeline. The stored procedure loads tens of millions of records into a synapse table from a parquet file. Yet the stored procedure activity in ADF succeeds fairly quickly. This led me to the suspicion that maybe the stored procedure performs the copy operation asynchronously in the background and succeeds the stored procedure activity before the data got copied completely.

Please confirm whether the stored procedure activity is a synchronous call or not.
I could find no documentation about this.

Comment: Yes Stored Proc activity calls in Azure Data Factory (ADF) and Synapse Pipelines are synchronous.  Maybe run the proc directly in Synapse Studio to get a comparison?  Also, if you are creating an external table, it's just a metadata operation really so could run pretty quick.

Comment: @wBob would you like to post the same as an answer so it can be marked as answered, if it was useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes Stored Proc activity calls in Azure Data Factory (ADF) and Synapse Pipelines are synchronous. Maybe run the proc directly in Synapse Studio to get a comparison? Also, if you are creating an external table, it's just a metadata operation really so could run pretty quick.